# Unable to load the file in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, http-post

**I have next code:**

```
var ordinaryPropertyValue = new Catalog.Core.Entities.OrdinaryPropertyValue();

Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

var fileFile = Request.Files["File" + prop.Id];

if (fileFile == null) continue;

string pathFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

fileFile.SaveAs(pathFile);

ordinaryPropertyValue.Value = pathFile;

instance.SetPropertyValue(prop.Id, ordinaryPropertyValue);
```

**But I can't load my file 'cos the next problem:**

AccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp' is denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help, but the real cause was not the problem with access, as you have said. 
The real reason was empty "" value. So i have remake my code such as:

```
var ordinaryPropertyValue = new Catalog.Core.Entities.OrdinaryPropertyValue();

var fileFile = Request.Files["File" + prop.Id];

if (fileFile == null)
    continue;

string pathFile = Server.MapPath("~/temp");

string filenameFile = Path.GetFileName(fileFile.FileName);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filenameFile))
{
    fileFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathFile, filenameFile));

    ordinaryPropertyValue.Value = Path.Combine(pathFile, filenameFile);

    instance.SetPropertyValue(prop.Id, ordinaryPropertyValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a security exception, executing user of your web application has no rights to write on the target path.

Notice that your are trying to save a file to a directory path without the file name.

Your code is a mess anyway, personally I would **NOT** assign/change the `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: I understand, that it is a security exception so, how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using IIS on your local machine, in which case you possibly need to grant write permission to this directory to the account that the web app is running under (using VS's built in server runs under your account).

If you are using IIS 7 + it's 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' otherwise it's 'NETWORK SERVICE'

P.S. I also don't recommend changing the environment settings.